# How do I use a specific cell to set a Named Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in excel which is populating my Named Range name, for example it will populate DataRange1 if first criteria is met, however how do I get the following code for Named Range item to populate with the cell (which is in Worksheet "Data" and cell E1)

Set nr = wb.Names.Item("DataRange1")

Comment: `Set nr = wb.Names.Item(wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("E1").Value)`? I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to know how to dynamically change which `Range` a `Name` Object refers to? Or do you want to change a cell's value based on a Named Range's value? Or do you want to set a `Range` object to a dynamically chosen `Name.RefersToRange` Object?

Comment: Perfect! Set nr = wb.Names.Item(wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("E1").Value) has worked!! That's what I needed thank you!